# Using darkmode in flutter paystack

Tags: flutter, user-interface, payment, darkmode, paystack

I'm trying to use [flutter_paystack](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paystack) in darkmode but I can't find a way around controlling the UI of the enter pin input. I've tried using the chargeCard option, but when pin is required, I get a pop-up with white background even with my mobile system setting is in dark mode. Same issue with using the checkout option.

[Paystack pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQbNN.png)

How can I make the background dark?